# How to set multiple queryString parameters in com.mashape.unirest.http.Unirest

Tags: java, rest

Hi I am new Rest and was developing API where in request parameters i get comes from client and it is different each time. I will then have to call another API. I want to write one method to get JSON data from 3rd party API. I checked online and all examples were same. I am using Unirest follpwing is what I have done

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions").
    header("accept",  "application/json").
    queryString("order","desc").
    queryString("sort", "creation").
    queryString("filter", "default").
    queryString("site", "stackoverflow").
    asJson();
```

Currently I have written all the queryString values.
Is there a way I can dynamically do this like put it in a map and give it to the method.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can pass it a Map ([Java source](https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mashape/unirest/request/HttpRequest.java)). The method signature is

```
public HttpRequest queryString(Map<String, Object> parameters)
```